# Text label for my abline with x axis having date value

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

I am struggling to get a label for my abline to plot:

I have the following procedure:

```
plot(mydata$date, mydata$Standerton,
type = "l",
col="brown", ylim = c(0.0,300), xlab='', ylab='', axis = T)
par(new=T)

abline(h="191", col="red")
text(05-11-2017, 200, "hello", pos = 4, col = "red", cex = 0.9)
```

My x-axis labels are dates. The format is `dd-mm-yy HM`.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem in your code is that you are passing 1st parameter as `05-11-2017` to the `text`. It actually gets converted to a numeric `(5-11-2017) => -2023` value which is not meaningful on x-axis.

The `text` expect 1st parameter as co-ordinate on x-axis. In your case the value of x-axis is in `date`. Hence, the 1st parameter to `text` is expected of type `date`. The correct syntax for text should be:

```
text(as.POSIXct("05-11-2017", tz="", format = "%d-%m-%Y"), 200, "hello",
                 pos = 4, col = "red", cex = 0.9)
```